# construct two shared_ptr objects from the same pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, tr1

I have a problem from "The C++ Standard Library Extensions":

> Exercise 6
>   I said in Section 2.4.2
>   that you shouldn't construct two
>   shared_ptr objects from the same
>   pointer. The danger is that both
>   shared_ptr objects or their progeny
>   will eventually try to delete the
>   resource, and that usually leads to
>   trouble. In fact, you can do this if
>   you're careful. It's not particularly
>   useful, but write a program that
>   constructs two
>   shared_ptr objects from
>   the same pointer and deletes the
>   resource only once.

below is my answer:

```
template <typename T>
void nonsence(T*){}
struct SX {
     int data;
     SX(int i = 0) :
              data(i) {
              cout << "SX" << endl;
     }
     ~SX() {
              cout << "~SX" << endl;
     }
};
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SX* psx=new SX;
    shared_ptr<SX> sp1(psx),sp2(psx,nonsence<SX>);
    cout<<sp1.use_count()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but I don't think it is a good solution--because i don't want solving it by use constructor. can anyone give me a better one?
thx, forgive my bad english.

Comment: You are missing a "{" in the SX constructor. (Just to be pedantic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the "STANDARD" answer from boost doc :
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5F38%5F0/libs/smart%5Fptr/sp%5Ftechniques.html#another_sp

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is construct the second `shared_ptr` from the first `shared_ptr`.

```
shared_ptr<SX> sp1( new SX );
shared_ptr<SX> sp2( sp1 );
```

The created SX will then properly be deleted only when all shared pointers to it are destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

The trick you found is valid, though useless. The central feature of `shared_ptr` is reference-counting, which you subvert here. The deleter (the second constructor argument) is there for using `shared_ptr` with resources other then plain pointers. You could use it with files, e.g:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr FilePtr;
void FileClose( FILE* pf ) { if ( pf ) fclose( pf ); }
FilePtr pfile( fopen( "filename" ), FileClose );
```

Same with database connections, sockets, etc. etc. and [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at how boost solves it with [shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html).  Here's the [code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.hpp).

Comment: thx a lot. 
I am find that boost sovle this problem by this:http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5F38%5F0/libs/smart%5Fptr/sp%5Ftechniques.html#another_sp. 
almost the same as mine.
thanks again.